# How to create two nodes, each containing three layers (PHY, MAC, APP) in OMNeT++?

Tags: networking, layer, omnet++, packet, application-layer

How to create two nodes, each containing three layers (PHY, MAC, APP) in OMNeT++? There should be at least two applications at each node. There should also be a wired or wireless connection among these nodes. Please help in defining the layers. I am confused about how to define them.

Comment: Welcome at SO! You did not mention network layer. Did you intentionally skip a network layer?

Comment: no no.. actually they mentioned these three...

Comment: What type of application would you like to add? What is desired behaviour of this application?

Answer (score 0):

A ready to use node is available in INET.
Take a look at [StandardHost](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.node.inet.StandardHost.html) - it contains all layers as well as an area to add own application in the Appplication Layer. There is a lot of samples how to use an application in folder `examples` of INET.